# PHP XPath 2.0 get highest value with max

Tags: php, xpath, max

I´ve a given XML structur:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phonebooks>
    <phonebook name="xxx" owner="1">
        <contact>
            ...
            <mod_time>1452420868</mod_time>
            <uniqueid>2026447</uniqueid>
        </contact>
        <contact>
        ...
        </contact>
    </phonebook>
</phonebooks>
```

And I need the highest value (latest timestamp) from `<mod_time>`

[xpathtester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) said, that `max(//mod_time)` will be allright.

So I tried in my script:

```
$modTime = $phonebook->xpath(max('//mod_time'));
```

which delivered me the warning

> max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array

Any quick help around?

Thx

Comment: `max` is __php core function__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the quotes to use the `fn:max` function and not the PHP function:

```
$modTime = $phonebook->xpath('max(//mod_time)');
```

Comment: As always, the solution is simple - but you do not get it yourself. Thx!